# Remove middle initial if present (Calculated Column)

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

I need to be able to remove a middle initial if it is present. The naming convention varies and they appear as either:

John Doe, John A Doe, or John A. Doe

I would like all names to be:

John Doe

Here is my current formula, this works in Excel:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))=2,LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1)),A1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `SEARCH` and  `REPLACE` to remove **dot** as the following

```
IF(ISERR(SEARCH(".",Title,1)),Title,REPLACE(Title,SEARCH(".",Title,1),1,""))
```

**[OutPut]**

[image]

---

To remove Initial Middle, Try this

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(" ",Title,1)),Title,REPLACE(Title,SEARCH(" ",Title,1),3," "))
```

**[OutPut]**

[image]

Comment: This only removes the period. I would like both the middle initial and period removed if present or just the middle initial.

Comment: Put -1 after the Search() to change the index and change the following character to 2. Use greater #'s if you want to remove extra spaces preceding/following it.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the update formula to work.  The formula in my original post works 100% in Excel but does not translate over to SharePoint.  Is there any part of my formula that isn't supported?

Comment: @FlatBanana the excel formula will not work in SharePoint it need alot of modification Meanwhile the above formula in my answer is meet your requirement as shown in the output, so what's the issue now in the above answer!!!!!

Comment: @M.Qassas I agree with you that it does work, but when there is no middle initial it does not.  If the name is John Brown, it comes out as John own.